# Three unexpected supports under stairs

Tags: stairs, support

I have a staircase that follows adjacent to a load bearing wall. Part of the staircase sticks out into the living/dining room area and I wanted to use the space underneath for storage. I cut out the plaster from the wall and found under the stairs three 2x4 boards that are under the stairs that run from the top to the bottom. They do not make contact with the stairs except for a few places where plywood has been jammed in.
Are they guides for installation that just got left or do they serve some other purpose?
I want to trim off the exposed section of the beam to open up the access a little more. [image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I do not think they are guides, they might be, but usually do not need guides.  With the plywood they might be stiffeners to make the stairs more solid.  How many plywood pieces on each one?

Comment: While you think they are “unexpected”, the suggestion is DO NOT REMOVE THEM”.

Comment: The plywood pieces are every 3 stairs for what I can see before it goes behind a wall. They don't even make contact with all three boards ( 1/2 in gaps for some between stair bottom and board) and are more like scrap shims than purpose cut pieces.

Comment: unclear which members you want to trim, can you highlight in photo?